# Windows.Forms open app from external uri

Tags: android-intent, callback, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, uri

I want to be able to open my app (Xamarin.Forms) from an external link. I need to be able to share a link that, when opened, it will open my App with extra data. Something like an Intent in Android but cross-platform-ish.
Is there something like that?

Comment: There is an official guide for this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/deep-linking/

Comment: I see they talk about deep-linking which works from searches. I want to be able to share a link via whatsapp (for example) and when the user clicks on that link, my app will start. Or maybe I didn't understand it?